# What is the derivative of x factorial?

Tags: derivatives

If the derivative of x factorial exists, what is it? I have tried calculating it on a Derivative Calculator but it doesn't seem to return a result.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: What is the definition of derivative? Have you tried to apply it to a factorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factorial function is only defined on nonnegative integers, so it doesn't have a derivative, but its generalization is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which has a derivative (see the Wikipedia page).

Answer (score 2):

On the Wikipedia page cited in other answers/comments, one finds the formula

$$\Gamma'(m+1) = m!\left( -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

for positive integers $m$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant ($\gamma \approx 0.57721$).

Since $m! = \Gamma(m+1)$, one could reasonably call this the derivative of $m!$ with respect to $m$ .

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $ x! = \Gamma(x+1)$ where $Gamma$ is Euler's gamma function

Comment: This does not reply the question, or provide any meaningful hint, does it?

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires : On the contrary, I think it does